# Event Bus Index

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, greenrobot-eventbus

Where/when should I add the index for Green Robot Event Bus library:

```
EventBus.builder().addIndex(new MyEventBusIndex()).installDefaultEventBus();
```

as described [here](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/subscriber-index/)? I've put this onCreate() method of my launcher activity, but sometimes I get:

```
Caused by: org.greenrobot.eventbus.h: Default instance already exists. It may be only set once before it's used the first time to ensure consistent behavior.
```

Where am I wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may want to put it in the constructor (without any arguments):
`public MainActivity() { EventBus.builder().addIndex(new MyEventBusIndex()).installDefaultEventBus(); }`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this once in your [Android Application class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

see [Configure the default EventBus instance](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/) in the documentation

> Note: this can be done only once before the default EventBus instance
>   is used the first time. Subsequent calls to installDefaultEventBus()
>   will throw an exception. This ensures consistent behavior in your app.
>   Your Application class is a good place to configure the default
>   EventBus instance before its used.